# Can I set a default page for an SSP application in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, ssp, suitecommerce

I'm creating a blog in NetSuite using an SSP application.

The SSP application sits at /blog and the SSP page is /blog/index.ssp

Is there any way at all to make that just /blog ? It would look so much better.

Is there some kind of trick, like a default index page like normal websites have. or some way to use a url component?
I know I can add a redirect from /blog to /blog/index.ssp but it still shows index.ssp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think thats possible. It requires lot of code development work.
U must need a sca version of netsuite
netsuite support memebers says that sca can be customised not created from scratch.contact netsuite for more info

alternatively u can setup a link for your third party blog in sca websites inside the netsuite

Comment: I worked out that is is possible to remove the .ssp extension from the file but that stops any tags from working. So, it's pretty much impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible to install any framework or platform like wordpress or magento inside netsuite ssp appication.

But for now the most and effective way of creating website in netsuite is to follow the way how SCA SuiteCommerce do or you also use that one instead. Because it uses the things that you are looking for like a url component.

Hope this one help.

Thanks,

Comment: I managed to speak to NS about this. It's just not possible it seems. I'll try to figure out how SCA does it.